# Fetched managedObject return null

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7

I created an IBAction that I link to saveButton, when I call all core data methods inside the IBAction it works fine in following code:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonTap:(id)sender{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectFor:@"Person" inManagedContext:context];

    [self setValue:firstNameTextField.text forKey:@"firstName"];
    [self setValue:lastNameTextField.text  forKey:@"lastName"];

    NSError *error   = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Can't save transaction - %@ || %@ ", error, [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

And when I separate the core data saving methods as the below, the saved firstName and lastName, showing null when fetched. It didn't return error, but I have no idea after googling all day. Could someone point anything wrong with my code?

**Person.h + Person.m**

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property(strong) NSString *firstName;
@property(strong) NSString *lastName;

- (void)save;
@end

@implementation Person

@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;

- (void)save{
    [self setValue:self.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
    [self setValue:self.lastName  forKey:@"lastName"];
}
@end
```

**mainViewController.h + mainViewController.m**

```
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong) ManagedObjectContext *context;
@property(strong) Person *person;

- (IBAction)saveButtonTap:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation mainViewController

@synthesize context;
@synthesize person;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    // ... some view did Load rituals
    if(context == nil){
        context = [self managedObjectContext]; // Assume this method calls for managed object context from shared application.
    }

    if(person == nil){
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectFor:@"Person" inManagedContext:context];
    }
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonTap:(id)sender{

    person.firstName = firstNameTextField.text;
    person.lastName  = lastNameTextField.text;

    [self.person save];

    NSError *error   = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Can't save transaction - %@ || %@ ", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
@end
```

Comment: Remove self in [self.person save];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of save function for Person.

> person.firstName = firstNameTextField.text

is equivalent to

> [self setValue:self.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];

What you need, is just this:

> - (IBAction)saveButtonTap:(id)sender{
>
>   person.firstName = firstNameTextField.text;
>
>   person.lastName  = lastNameTextField.text;
>
>   NSError *error   = nil;
>
>   if (![context save:&error])
>
>   ```
>   NSLog(@"Can't save transaction - %@ || %@ ", error, [error localizedDescription]);
>   ```
>
>   }

But, I am not sure whether this is the cause of the issue. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Harris, it helped me with debugging and understanding how to subclass the NSManagedObject class. But I still don't know how the logic behind works. When I assigned a value to the class properties, then call the setValue to its properties, isn't it similar to saying firstName = firstName and lastName = lastName ? (please correct me if I am wrong) but instead, it returns 'null'.

Comment: I was thinking the same and thats why, was not sure whether this can cause issue. But, we cannot know the internals. It is more likely that the setting value using property, invokes setValue: and if this call is being done asynchronously it is difficult to predict when the actual value will be set (why this kind of stuff would be done, only apple knows).